# Geting segmentation fault while implementing bubble sort on list

Tags: c

I am trying to implement bubble sort on the list type data structure but it's showing segmentation fault. Although the function is not completed, I wanted to check whether it will work or not. I thought the largest number will be shifted to the first position but I am not able to verify it now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct list {
    int numb ;
    struct list* next ; 
} list ;

list* create_list (int numb) {
    list* head = malloc(sizeof(list)) ;
    head->numb = numb ;
    head->next = NULL ;
    return (head) ;
}

list* add_front(int numb, list* h) {
    list* head = create_list(numb) ;
    head->next = h ;
    return (head) ;
}

list* array_to_list(int data[], int size) {
    list* head = create_list(data[0]) ;
    int i ;
    for (i=1; i<size; i++){
        head = add_front(data[i], head) ;
    }
    return (head) ;
}

void print_list(list* h) {
    while(h != NULL) {
        printf("%d : ", h->numb) ;
        h = h->next ;
    }
}

list* sort(list* h) {
    list temp1, *temp2 ;
    temp1.numb = h->numb ;
    temp2 = h->next ;
    while(h!=NULL) {
        if((temp2->numb)>=temp1.numb) {
            h->numb = temp2->numb ; }
        else {
            h->numb = temp1.numb ; }   
        temp2 = temp2->next  ;  
    }
    return (h) ;
}

int main()
{
    list* head ;
    int numb[10], n, i;
    srand(time(0)) ;
    n = sizeof(numb)/sizeof(numb[0]) ;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        numb[i] = rand() % 101 ;
    }
    
    head = array_to_list(numb, n) ;
    head = sort(head) ;
    print_list(head) ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

while I skip the sorting step rest of the program works fine. (coded in C)

Comment: Take a look at `sort`. The loop `while(h!=NULL)` will end when and only when `h` is `NULL` (in C++ you should prefer `nullptr`). Right after this you `return (h) ;`. So, `sort` will always return `NULL`.

Comment: Please pick only one between C and C++, they're different languages. The code looks like it's C

Comment: It sounds like a great opportunity to use your debugger to see what code gets run, in what order, and what all variables' values are - and compare the reality to your assumptions.

Comment: I am using the online C compiler. and I also tried in different online compilers but the result is same. segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: If you want to seriously learn programming, you should install a C compiler on your computer. Preferably use one with an IDE and a good debugger. There are free options around.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in how you iterate over the list, at the moment you are looping

```
while(h!=NULL)
```

but you are updating temp2 instead of h, which means the condition is tested against h, that is always pointing to the same thing, while *temp2* is changing to *temp2->next* until it eventually becomes NULL and you get a segfault in the

```
if((temp2->numb)>=temp1.numb)
```

I tried adapting your while condition to test against temp2 but the overall structure of the loop seemed off to me, so I did a minor refactor that looks clearer to me (please take it only as a suggestion)

```
list* sort(list* h) {
    list* cur = h;    // pointer to currently considered node
    int tmp;          // tmp variable, needed for swapping
    while (cur->next != NULL) {   // stop iterating once reaching the end of the list
        if ((cur->next->numb) >= cur->numb) {   // if the number of the next node is bigger
            tmp = cur->next->numb;  // then swap
            cur->next->numb = cur->numb;
            cur->numb = tmp;
        }  // else do nothing (already in descending order)

        cur = cur->next;  // move to next node
    }
  return (h);
}
```

This will simply move a single small number as much to the right as possible, since you are still missing the second of the two loops needed to implement bubble sort.

Hope I cleared up some doubts

Comment: thanks alot man for these efforts! This absorbed my whole day but now happy to found the mistake as well as approach. ☺️

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry I couldn't stick to your solution but as long as you understood what wasn't working I'm happy :D EDIT: also, if you think it could be useful, you could try writing the bubble sort algorithm for an array, and then adapt it to work on a list